# ldd command in Linux

Tags: linux, dynamic-loading

```
samuel@PC:~/tmp111/MediaSDK/build/__bin/debug$ ldd simple_3_encode
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe77af2000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2ff068f000)
        libva.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.2 (0x00007f2ff0468000)
        libva-drm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.2 (0x00007f2ff0265000)
        libmfx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmfx.so.1 (0x00007f2ff0052000)
```

I knew the meaning of the number behind the `.so` extension, so that when link to `-lXXX` the linker will find the `xxx.so` which link to `xxx.so.N`.

But I don't understand is that why it shows `xxxx.so.1` or `xxxx.so.2` instead of xxxx.so. That mean the excutable file will try to find `xxxx.so.1` or `xxxx.so.2` instead of trying to find `xxx.so`?

If so, another PC don't have `foo.so.2` but `foo.so.1` That PC can not run the program?

Comment: Versioning in modern languages has come a long way from the crudeness of the 1980s.  In a nutshell, I think you have it.   There is a good answer over here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work

Comment: ps: if not for the brilliance of versioning, containers and docker would never need to exist :)

Comment: But libva.so.2 is also a link which link to libva.so.2.8.xxx.

Comment: which is fine, and if you update libva to libva.so.2.9.xxx, your program, which depends upon libva.so.2, will be ok; but if you update to libva.so.3, your program will refuse to bind to it.  (If I remember this properly).